# How can I integrate WinUI 3 into existing MFC Application? Are there any supporting books or study material showing the process of integrating?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, winui-3

I would like to integrate WinUI 3 into an existing MFC Application. How can I integrate WinUI 3 into existing MFC Application? Are there any supporting books or study material showing the process of integrating? I could not find anything. Please help out.

Please guide me how to integrate WinUI 3 into an existing MFC Application.

Comment: [Modernize your desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/). I'm not aware of any books on the subject. There's a lot of information scattered around the MSDN, and you'll essentially have to put all the pieces together, filter out content that doesn't (or no longer) applies, and pretty much discover what's required on your own.

Comment: The solution should be XAML Islands for WinUI3 (as opposed to XML Islands for UWP). That was in the roadmap https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md when the roadmap was updated (!). Now, it's unclear if it's there (I don't think so but I may be wrong) or if it ever will be. There's some notion of "island" in current experimental version but not sure it's not the other way around (hosting win32/MFC/HWND into WinUI3 app) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/experimental-channel